# Create subsets based on output of the value_counts function

Tags: python, pandas, subset, missing-data

My dataset looks as follows:

| Area | Year | Value | Crop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1961 | 1000 | Corn |
| Afghanistan | 1961 | 1100 | Potato |
| Afghanistan | 1961 | 1200 | Wheat |
| Afghanistan | 1962 | 1304 | Potato |
| Afghanistan | 1962 | 1923 | Corn |
| Bhutan | 1961 | 1236 | Corn |
| Bhutan | 1961 | 1836 | Potato |
| Bhutan | 1961 | 1031 | Wheat |
| Bhutan | 1962 | 1111 | Corn |

I have a total of 60 years of data under consideration, with each country able to contain a max of one row per crop per year- to a total of 240 rows per year.
I have used the `.value_counts` function to evaluate which countries are not whole and would like to create a subset containing only the countries that have a complete set of data (ie. where the `.value_counts` function returned a value of 240 for that country).

I have tried doing this as follows:
`df_240 = df.loc[df["Area"].value_counts == 240]` however I am having no luck.

The error I am recieving is:

> KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [grouping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by 'Area' and fetching 'Year' data is passed to [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) where 'count' is used for counting. It turns out a logical mask, which is substituted for selecting rows. Indexes are dropped and [drop=True](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is applied.

```
import pandas as pd

ind = df.groupby('Area')['Year'].transform('count') >= 240
df1 = df[ind].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["Area", "Year"]).filter(lambda x: len(x) == 240)
```

Comment: I've tried this too! It's returning an empty dataset for me for some reason